# how to change save image Orientation in Portitate mode in android using Surfaceholder

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView image;
    Activity context;
    Preview preview;
    static Camera camera;
    Button exitButton;
    ImageView fotoButton;
    LinearLayout progressLayout;
    String path = "/sdcard/KutCamera/cache/images/";
    public static int count = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        context = this;

        fotoButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_foto);
        exitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_exit);
        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_photo);
        progressLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.progress_layout);

        preview = new Preview(this,
                (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.KutCameraFragment));
        FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview);
        frame.addView(preview);
        preview.setKeepScreenOn(true);
        fotoButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    takeFocusedPicture();
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
                exitButton.setClickable(false);
                fotoButton.setClickable(false);
                progressLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (camera == null) {
            camera = Camera.open();
            camera.startPreview();
            camera.setErrorCallback(new ErrorCallback() {
                public void onError(int error, Camera mcamera) {

                    camera.release();
                    camera = Camera.open();
                    Log.d("Camera died", "error camera");

                }
            });
        }
        if (camera != null) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14)
                setCameraDisplayOrientation(context,
                        CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK, camera);
            preview.setCamera(camera);
        }
    }

    public static void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity,
            int cameraId, android.hardware.Camera camera) {
        android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info = new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
        android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
        int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                .getRotation();
        int degrees = 0;
        switch (rotation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
            degrees = 0;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            degrees = 90;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            degrees = 180;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
            degrees = 270;
            break;
        }

        int result;
        if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
            result = (360 - result) % 360; // compensate the mirror
        } else { // back-facing
            result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
        }
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
    }

    Camera.AutoFocusCallback mAutoFocusCallback = new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {

            try {

                camera.takePicture(mShutterCallback, null, jpegCallback);


            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

        }
    };

    Camera.ShutterCallback mShutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onShutter() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };

    public void takeFocusedPicture() {
        camera.autoFocus(mAutoFocusCallback);

    }

    PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {

        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

            FileOutputStream outStream = null;
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            File videoDirectory = new File(path);

            if (!videoDirectory.exists()) {
                videoDirectory.mkdirs();
            }

            try {
                // Write to SD Card
                outStream = new FileOutputStream(path
                        + c.getTime().getSeconds() + ".jpg");
                outStream.write(data);

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image:" + count, 1000)
                        .show();
                count++;

                outStream.close();
                if (count == 3) {
                    finish();
                }

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {

            }

            Bitmap realImage;
            final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 5;
            options.inPurgeable = true; 
            options.inInputShareable = true;
            realImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length,
                    options);

            if (data != null) {

                int screenWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
                int screenHeight = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;

                if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                    // Notice that width and height are reversed
                    Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(realImage,
                            screenHeight, screenWidth, true);
                    int w = scaled.getWidth();
                    int h = scaled.getHeight();
                    // Setting post rotate to 90
                    Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
                    mtx.postRotate(90);
                    // Rotating Bitmap
                    realImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaled, 0, 0, w, h, mtx,
                            true);
                } else {

                    Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(realImage,
                            screenWidth, screenHeight, true);
                    realImage = scaled;
                }

            }

            image.setImageBitmap(realImage);

            fotoButton.setClickable(true);
            camera.startPreview();
            progressLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            exitButton.setClickable(true);

        }
    };

}
```

This is my code using this i am taking Picture from camera and save in Sdcard in given path i am taking image from camera in portrait mode its working fine and save in Sd card But saved Image when i  open its Landscape Mode but i want keep it in portrait mode but  i am  trying change many thing in surface holder class and even Main actvity class not chaining while if set camera preview in land scape then its saved Image saving in portrait mode while i want camera preview and saved image in Sd card both should in portrait mode please suggest me how to do this

Comment: Yours question is hard to understand. Try to split it on several complete and meaningful sentences.

Comment: we have one more class which code is this http://paste.ofcode.org/SJm6HrnUpLLh95uWkM4Hgf

Comment: i had the same issue please refer below answer it work for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

same issue i was facing but using this code its work for me try this code:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                matrix.postRotate(90);    
                Bitmap bitmapFinal=null;

                bitmapFinal = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                bmp.recycle();
                bmp=null;

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                if(imageFormat.equals("jpg")||imageFormat.equals("jpeg"))
                {
                    bitmapFinal.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100,fos);
                }
                else if(imageFormat.equals("png"))
                {
                    bitmapFinal.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100,fos);
                }
                else 
                {
                    bitmapFinal.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100,fos);
                }

                bitmapFinal.recycle();
                bitmapFinal=null;

                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
                fos=null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code to rotate change image orientation

```
URI imageUri = data.getData();
ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(getRealPathFromURI(imageUri));
int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

// float angle = 0;
switch (orientation) {
case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
    // angle= 90;
    temp = rotate(temp, 90f);
    break;
case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
    // angle= 180;
    temp = rotate(temp, 180f);
    break;
case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
    // angle= 270;
    temp = rotate(temp, 270f);
    break;
}
```

Comment: define rotate function and pass rotate angle and bitmap

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/cf3irPrLN7KgJLf8yV6zQs  this method i have create please check it s right

Comment: and what is temp can u please give me complete code

Comment: in your public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)

Bitmap temp = decodeUri(data.getData());

Comment: temp is your bitmap that you get in onActivityResult()

like Bitmap temp = decodeUri(data.getData());

and pass it to rotate ()

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/TBJ6w5m3Mq3eGSvysX876F  check this is it correct but problem am unable to save image now

Comment: where u want to save your image

Comment: plase refer the below code to save image in loacal disk

Comment: please mark up vote if my code help full for you thnk you

Comment: @ResearchDevelopment what you are trying to do actully

Comment: i want to save image in Prtriate mode not in Landscape this i want coz if take image in Prtriate mode then it should save in same not other orientaion

Answer (score 0):

please try below rotate function just pass your bitmap and angle

```
public static Bitmap rotate(Bitmap source, float angle) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(angle);
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(),
                source.getHeight(), matrix, false);
    }
```

Comment: u not undersatding what i am telling i am taking image in Poritate mode so it should save in portriate mode while it always save in landscape mode in sd card

Answer (score 0):

save image in local syatem

```
public static void saveImageTolacal(Bitmap bitmapImage,Context context){
//          String path = "/sdcard";
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +  "/folder/";
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            File videoDirectory = new File(path);
            if (!videoDirectory.exists()) {
                videoDirectory.mkdirs();
            }
        try {
                // Write to SD Card
             File mypath=new File(videoDirectory , c.getTime().getSeconds() + ".jpg");
            fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
            System.out.println("------absolute path-----"+mypath.getAbsolutePath());
            bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            notifyMediaScannerService(context,mypath.getAbsolutePath());
            fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
            }
        }
```

Comment: yaar my code was working fine  posted code is sucessfully save i just replace ur code to my code then i am unable to save the file

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/hKndQXKUBWK2bsvZQjDhMR  this code from which i am able to save image and take image working fine i am just replacing ur code in to mine

Answer (score 0):

```
   ExifInterface exif;    
        try {
            exif = new ExifInterface(getRealPathFromURI(imageUri));    
            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                    ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0);
            Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            if (orientation == 6) {
                matrix.preRotate(90);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            } else if (orientation == 3) {
                matrix.preRotate(180);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            } else if (orientation == 9) {
                matrix.preRotate(270);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            }
            scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,
                    bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix,
                    true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```